# Finding a Sum of Series in Python

Tags: python

Write a python program that calculate the sum of the series: (1,2,9,28, ... , 1000001). The sum of that series is represented using the equation below. Find the value of y and print it.

I can't figure it out

Comment: What equation below?

Comment: I think you meant to provide an equation, but it doesn't appear in your question. Additionally, can you tell us what you've tried, and focus the question on precisely what aspect of your code you're struggling with? thanks

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the equation, I'm just going to give general advice.

If we imagine that our education is: x*2 {from 0 to 20}, we can use a list and the sum() function to solve it.

```
result = sum([x*2 for x in range(0,21)])
```